# How to display full correlation matrix in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, spyder, correlation

I am calculating the correlation matrix for a dataset in Python Spyder using the command df.corr(). However, the output shows the matrix values only for the first two and the last two columns. What command should I use so that I can get the entire matrix?

I am using the pandas package for calculation the correlation matrix of a given dataset.

The code I used for calculating the correlation matrix is:

```
correlation_matrix = df.corr()
print(correlation_matrix)
```

The result of this is that the correlation matrix values for the first two columns and the last two columns are getting displayed. I want the entire matrix to be displayed.

Comment: Can't reproduce

Comment: I think it will only show the matrix for numerical data. Are your other column of object type>

Comment: Yes, some columns are of other types

Comment: can you add some sample data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is might be because of the default print options of the `pandas` package.

Try the following.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.height', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```

Sometimes, when your data frame has non-numeric columns, then those would be excluded when computing correlation. This would result in lesser number of columns in the `corr()` output.

Comment: I think this isn't OP's issue, since the default is to print more than two. @Mohit Motwani's answer in the comments seems more likely

Comment: Not sure. My thinking is that output of `corr()` would be a dataframe with numerical values alone but @Mohit's point is valid that the corr cannt computed for objects!